# Чем можно заменить метод replaceAll \ replace в jenkins.groovy? (Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod)

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Пытаюсь настроить Pipeline в Jenkins.
На вход, параметром принимаю строку тегов.

Пытаюсь разбить полученную строку в массив, но при попытке откинуть лишнее через replaceAll
получаю ошибку:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods replaceAll java.lang.String java.util.regex.Pattern java.lang.String
```

исполняемый код:

```
task_tags = "${TEST_TAGS_NAME}"
def tags_cutted = task_tags.replaceAll(~/^\[|\]$/, '').split(',').collect{it as String}
```

Comment: Ваша задача решается без использования регулярок, вырезать пару символов по такому шаблону не сложно даже ручками в цикле :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как выяснилось, проблема была не в наличии replaceAll, а в шаблоне.
в итоге сделал просто:
`def tags_cutted = task_tags.replace(' ', '').split(',').collect{it as String}`